# Regex to remove password from file

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, awk

we have running tomcat server and in server.xml file we have password=secret I want to search and replace my password with xxxxxxx string. how do i craft regex for it? following is line where password i located in server.xml file

```
<Resource auth="Container" description="Database connection for Production" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="25" maxIdle="5" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/osdb" password="secret" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB0001" username="admin"/>
```

Comment: [Why on earth would you want to parse XML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like:

```
sed -i 's/password="[a-zA-Z0-9]\+"/password="foo"/g' server.xml
```

do the job for you or are you expecting there to be other lines like password="xyz" ?

Comment: You don't even need [a-zA-Z0-9] as he already gave you the string to replace ("secret").

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9] is required because we have 2/3 different passwords in same file. ("secret") was example :)

Comment: @Pollett I suggest you use `[[:alnum:]]` over `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as not only is it shorter but it also works across all locales

Comment: I have encounter is new problem. I have few passwords which has special character like #!@%^& so [a-zA-Z0-9] regex doesn't working there. How do i match special character in regexp